# Why is pandas.to_sql trying to create a table even though I specified to append if_exists?

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata, pandas-to-sql

Here's my code. Simply trying to append a dataframe to a Teradata table.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy_teradata

user = username
pasw = password
host = hostname
port = port

td_engine = create_engine('teradata://'+host+':'+port+'/?username='+user+'&password='+pasw)
td_engine = td_engine.execution_options(autocommit=True)

cnxn = td_engine.connect()
df.to_sql('mydatabase.existing_table', cnxn, if_exists='append' , index=False)
cnxn.close()
```

The error says it is trying to create a table and I don't have rights to do so even though I specified if_exists='append' and I do, in fact, have rights to create tables.

```
(teradata.api.DatabaseError) (3524, '[42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database](-3524)The user does not have CREATE TABLE access to database my_username.')
```

Comment: Note that `teradata` and `sqlalchemy-teradata` packages are deprecated. Better to use `teradatasql` driver / dialect and `teradatasqlalchemy`. But the actual problem is that you need to specify the databasename via the optional `schema=` keyword. The first parameter for `to_sql` is an *unqualified* tablename so it's checking for / trying to create a table named "mydatabase.existing_table" in your session default database. And apparently you have CREATE TABLE rights on "mydatabase" but not "my_username".

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `if_exists='append'`, pandas tries to append the data to an existing table.
Check if the table exists before using `pandas.to_sql`. You can use **SQLAlchemy's** `inspect`.

```
cnxn = td_engine.connect()

# Check if the table exists
inspector = inspect(cnxn)
table_exists = inspector.has_table('mydatabase.existing_table')

if not table_exists:
    # Create the table if it doesn't exist
    df.to_sql('mydatabase.existing_table', cnxn, index=False)

# Append the data
df.to_sql('mydatabase.existing_table', cnxn, if_exists='append', index=False)

cnxn.close()
```